# Preg Replace Numerals

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm a newbie to `preg_replace` function. I have the following expression that I want to replace the numbers `0-9` with  `#` in a string. It's returning the same string with no changes, where could I have gone wrong? I tried google but still cannot find the solution. Thanks.

```
$phonenumber = "0720123456";
    $format = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "#", $phonenumber));
```

Answer (score 4):

`[^0-9]` will match **anything except a digit**.

You need to use `[0-9]` or shortcut `\d`:

```
$format = trim(preg_replace("/\d/", "#", $phonenumber));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `/[0-9]/` as your regular expression.

Your expression `/[^0-9]/` means to replace any character, but **not** (by `^`) numerals.

Example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$phonenumber = "0720123456";
$format = trim(preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "#", $phonenumber));

echo $format;
?>
```

Result:

```
##########
```

Comment: It makes sense to explain what was wrong with the original regex. You want to teach him fishing not feed with fish, don't you?